# How use setState() in useState() with several items

Tags: reactjs

In my React functional component, I have some data like this for example.

```
{ name:"Abdelrahman", age:"25", id:"1" }
```

I need to be able to update fields in this object with the `useState` hook. How do I use it?

```
const [name, setName] = useState([{name:"Abdelrahman", age:"25", id:"1"}]}
```

the setName will update the name only, so how to update the age too?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-using-multiple-state-variables

Comment: Do you really want to add use an array in useState or a single object?

Comment: Think to useReducer in these cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name you define for your state variable is just an alias to whatever data you pass as a parameter to `useState`. Naming is up to you.. Here, I'd change it to be something more relevant to what it is supposed to be and it will be clearer.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([{ name:"Abdelrahman", age:"25", id:"1" }]}
```

Here the alias `users` is equivalent to `[{ name:"Abdelrahman", age:"25", id:"1" }]`. 
You can add a new user via.

```
const newUser = { name:"BillyBob", age:"50", id:"2" }
setUsers([...users, newUser]);
```

Or you can just change the age of a user (with id 1):

```
setUsers(users.map(user => user.id === 1 ? {...user, age: 10}));
```

Big thing to remember here is whatever you pass inside `setUsers` will replace whatever was there previously (which behaves differently than a class components `setState` method).

Answer (score 0):

There are two things which will help you to think if you understand correctly.
First:

const [name, setName] = useState("")

The empty string in useState is the default value.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("")
  return (
    <input type="text" onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
  );
}
```

So, from the above code you can understand whenever you change the input, onChange handler will be called which'll update `name`.

**Optimzation**:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("")
  const onInputChange = useCallback(e => setName(e.target.value))
  return (
    <input type="text" onChange={onInputChange} />
  );
}
```

Use useCallback for memoizing your handlers.

Similarly, have separate states for age if required.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to understand is that **name** & **setName** are userdefined you can give whatever name you want. You are putting the **setName** it does not mean that you will be able to update only **name** of given object. **setName** can update the each key,value pair of object inside array i.e. **[{name:"Abdelrahman", age:"25", id:"1"}]**

```
const [name, setName] = useState([{name:"Abdelrahman", age:"25", id:"1"}]
```

Here **name** refers to whole array object i.e. name = [{name:"Abdelrahman", age:"25", id:"1"}]

To update the age both you can use write code like

```
onClick = {()=> setName(name.map(item => item.id == 1 ? {...item, age: "40"})}
```